# Android timepicker not showing selected am/pm color

Tags: android, timepicker

[image: time picker dialogue image]

Time picker styles

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme.TimePicker" parent="android:Widget.Material.TimePicker">
    <item name="android:timePickerMode">clock</item>
    <item name="android:headerBackground">@color/header_color</item>
    <item name="android:numbersTextColor">@color/text_color_primary</item>
    <item name="android:numbersSelectorColor">@color/accent_color</item>
    <item name="android:numbersBackgroundColor">@color/button_color</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/button_color</item>
    <item name="android:amPmTextColor">@color/delete_color</item>
</style>
```

It's not highlighting whether am is selected or pm

Answer (score 0):

hourOfDay will always be 24 hours. If you open the dialog with is24HourView set to false, the user does not have to process the time in 24-hour format, but Android converts it to 24-hour format when onTimeSet() is called.

Comment: I think you got my question wrong, am asking that in the image I shared it's not highlighting whether AM is selected or PM.